# Rails edit_user route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

After incorporating friendly URLs, my `edit_user` path is not routing to the `users#edit` action.  The rendered URL from the `edit_user_path` helper is correct.  Whenever I click on the link, it first attempts to go to the correct URL, then redirects the `root` action.

Route: `edit_user_path     GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit`

Link ERB: `<%= link_to 'Edit Account', edit_user_path(@user), class: 'button' %>`

Rendered HTML: `http://localhost:3000/users/plopp/edit`

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_signin, except: [:new, :create]
  before_action :require_correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by!(username: params[:id])
    @reviews = @user.reviews
    @favorite_movies = @user.favorite_movies
  end

  def edit    
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Account successfully updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).
    permit(:name, :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def require_correct_user
    User.find_by!(username: params[:id])
    unless current_user?(@user)
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have mistake in `#require_correct_user`

```
  def require_correct_user
    @user = User.find_by!(username: params[:id])
    unless current_user?(@user)
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

You should find and assign user to variable `@user`
Before processing `#edit` action runs `#require_correct_user` method because of

```
 before_action :require_correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

It's checking current user by `#current_user?` helper passing `@user` variable, so before that check you should assign user to that variable

Comment: That did the trick.  Every time I come across a bug like this that I spend hours trying too track down, it ends up being such an obvious oversight.  I hope that gets better as I get more experience.